# How to create layout_weight for vertical and horizontal at the same time in a RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want a layout like below image for the item of a RecyclerView: 
[image: UI Layout]

Below is my XML Item script:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

What changes to be needed so that vertical and horizontal weight will be applied on layout at same time using `Linear Layout`?

Comment: weight will do or data is coming from backend?

Comment: How do you intend to do that? `Portrait` or `Landscape`? I'd go with `ConstraintView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `LinearLayout` You can use something like this:

```
[LinearLayout ]   [LinearLayout ]
[child 1]         [child 1](takes full screen height)
[child 2]
```

Here is the XML for it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put it in `Linear Layout` and provide `weight` to your each layouts

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/myText"
                android:text="Hello"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/newText"
                android:text="NEW Text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:id="@+id/Newtext"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I don't think that you are using any of  `RelativeLayout` properties. If that's the case why not use `LinearLayout` as a parent? I did it in my answer to this question, would love to have you opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your helps!
And this is my exact answer from your helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:weightSum="1"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.4">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/d"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.6">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:checked="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```